WPF TextBox typing issue with StringFormat
Is there a way to "bypass" the dot and "override" the decimals when typing a value in a TextBox in WPF formatted with a 2 decimals via StringFormat='{}{0:F2} ?
When I type "1.23" to the TextBox which initially shows "0.00", it writes "1.23.00". I don't want to type "1" then move after the dot with the right arrow and then type "23".
Should I process the typed text in the code-behind to handle the dot and adjust the typed text or is there a more straightforward way to achieve it?

You coukd try setting this property false https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkcompatibilitypreferences.keeptextboxdisplaysynchronizedwithtextproperty?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Did you try hanging the culture? It might be that decimal character is handled automatically in WPF cntrols

I don't think that that added FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false; has an impact (I added it to the App constructor) and haven't investigate how to handle the culture.
I quickly coded this callback which seems to work:
private static void tbx_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var tbx = sender as TextBox;

    var text = tbx.Text;

    if (e.Key == Key.Decimal) // '.' is processed as decimal separator?
    {
        tbx.CaretIndex += 1;

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    if (e.Key == Key.Delete && text[tbx.CaretIndex] == '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

